# Трансляция с камеры в WebView

Tags: java, android

Задача: надо сделать отображение камеры в webview. Что пришло на ум: использовать MediaRecorder для записи видео в сокет. Поднять на устройстве веб-сервер( например использовать NanoHTTPD). На веб-сервере поднять страницу, с js скриптом для приема данных их конвертацию и отображение. Ниже приведен код записи с MediaRecorder в сокет.

```
String hostname = "your.host.name";
int port = 1234;

Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), port);
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
// Additional MediaRecorder setup (output format ... etc.) omitted
recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

[Оригинал](http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system). Как я понял код пишет данные в mp4(зависит от настроек MediaRecorder) в сокет. Возникает вопрос: как это все отображать на стороне js? По идее я должен это все привести к след. форме 192.168.0.1:8088/ucking_hdmi.mp4. Но как этого добиться?

Answer (score 0):

Вот ссылка на такой же проект на [Github](https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye). Там вроде как html5 используется. Реализация такая же, как вы задумали

Comment: Это не рабочий проект, там нехватает файлов.